# voiceover function disable on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, voiceover

Can you turn off the voiceover function on a particular web page? 
Or can I delete audio with js - jquery on the DOM page?
(like when Chrome disables the sound of a tab)

i want turn off VoiceOver function on a specific webpage!

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Comment: Why would you turn off VoiceOver function on a webpage? This question needs more detail... what do you think the problem the user is going to have is? Code is great as well.